# Is there a way to make form values non nonNullable by default?

Tags: angular, typescript

My form

```
  public loginForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]),
  });
```

When getting the values of the form, this is its type

```
getRawValue(): {
  username: string | null;
  password: string | null;
}
```

I know I could do like this to suppress the null's

```
  public loginForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true, validators: [Validators.required] }),
    password: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true, validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)] }),
  });
```

---

**But is there a way to make all the form control non nunllable by default?**

If my form contains a lot of control, I would have to use  `nonNullable: true` on all of it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [NonNullableFormBuilder](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formbuilder-and-nonnullableformbuilder), this way you remove the boilerplate associated with setting nonNullable

```
  const fb = new FormBuilder();
  const loginForm = fb.nonNullable.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
  });
```

another [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e9zdbi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the injector:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  loginForm: FormGroup
  
  constructor(private readonly fb: NonNullableFormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = fb.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    });
  }

}
```